# Remove newlines unless preceded by

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need to remove extra new-lines from some text. I only need to keep the new-lines that are immediately preceded by a full stop / period character `.`.

In the example text below, I only need to keep 2 new-lines: one after `...arcu rhoncus.` and one after `...ac in est.`.

```
Donec viverra mi quis quam pulvinar at malesuada arcu rhoncus.
Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur
ridiculus mus. In rutrum accumsan ultricies. Mauris vitae nisi at sem facilisis
semper ac in est.
Vivamus fermentum semper porta. Nunc diam velit, adipiscing ut tristique
vitae, sagittis vel odio. Maecenas convallis ullamcorper ultricies. Curabitur
ornare, ligula semper consectetur sagittis, nisi diam iaculis velit, id 
fringilla sem nunc vel mi.
```

I am using notepad++ for this.

I can match what I want to keep with the below, but I am not sure how I can make the whole solution.

```
[.]$
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you also keep the newline after "malesuada arcu rhoncus." on the first line?

Comment: This is easy if lookbehind is supported: `(?<!\. *)\n` can you test?

Comment: Do you know if your newlines are DOS, *NIX, or MAC newlines?  ie which combination of CR and/or LF?

Comment: Good point Sepster, it was a quick example that I used and didn't think about too much - but you're correct.

Comment: @aland OK, just clarifying - quite often with regex questions the "devil is in the detail" - so any conflicting info in the OP's requirements definition can lead to hours of updates/alterations to answers.  Looks like you got what you needed, glad to hear it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like suggested [in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526473/remove-newlines-unless-preceeded-by#comment21993049_15526473) a negative look-behind works well.   Search for this regexp in Notepad++ and replace with a single space:

```
(?<!\.)\s*\r\n\s*
```

If you only have have `\n` instead of `\r\n` then just remove the `\r`.

Note that when using `\r?` Notepad++ seems to match non-greedy so the `\r` won't be removed.

Result with Notepad++ v6.1.5 (UNICODE):

```
Donec viverra mi quis quam pulvinar at malesuada arcu rhoncus.
Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In rutrum accumsan ultricies. Mauris vitae nisi at sem facilisis semper ac in est.
Vivamus fermentum semper porta. Nunc diam velit, adipiscing ut tristique vitae, sagittis vel odio. Maecenas convallis ullamcorper ultricies. Curabitur ornare, ligula semper consectetur sagittis, nisi diam iaculis velit, id fringilla sem nunc vel mi.
```

Comment: Looks like look behind isn't support on notepad++ :(

Comment: @aland It is, I just tried your example with my regexp and it works (Notepad++ v6.1.5 (UNICODE)).

Comment: +1 nice one.  I didn't think look-arounds worked in NP++ either so didn't bother going down that path, so looks like I need an upgrade too! Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use negative lookbehind and replace with space:

```
(?<!\.)\r\n
```

Another option for someone that doesn't know this construct (or if lookbehind is not supported), would be to first replace all occurences of `\.\r\n` with something distinct like `<rnt>` string, then remove all newlines, and then replace `<rnt>` with `\.\r\n` again.

Comment: Thanks also for the 'workaround' where lookbehind isn't supported

Answer (score 2):

Here is a non-look-behind method:

Search for:

```
([^.])(\r\n)+
```

And replace with:

```
\1
```

Where `\1` is followed by a space.

Note the `+` is needed to match multiple newlines in a row.  Otherwise, not all newlines would match.