# Regex in Vim trying to remove newline character if it isn't preceded by a period

Tags: regex, vim

I'm working in Vim and I have some text data that I'm trying to clean up that looks like this `* denotes space`.

```
 I saw* 

 the dog run.
 I played catch*
 with*
 my friend.
 It was a*
 nice day today.
```

And I'd like to remove the newline character if it isn't preceded by a period (.) so the data will end up looking like this.

```
 I saw the dog run.
 I played catch with my friend.
 It was a nice day today.
```

Looking at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526473/remove-newlines-unless-preceded-by) I tried the following command but can't get it to work.

```
:%s/(?<!\.*) \n/ /gc
```

and

```
:%s/(?<!\.)\s* \n\s*/ /gc
```

Answer (score 2):

In Vim, you should use

```
\(\.\)\@<!\n\s*
```

**Details**

- `\(\.\)\@<!` - a negative lookbehind that matches a location that is not immediately preceded with a dot
- `\n` - a newline
- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespaces.

Comment: I suggest using very magick and avoiding the group once in the group we have a single characther, the command becomes easy to read: `%s,\v\.@<!\n+\s*,,`

Comment: @SergioAraujo That  is a matter of taste, I prefer to work in the usual mode when working in Vi(m).

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of vim's `\zs` :

```
:%s/[^.]\zs\n\+//
```

- `\zs` check `:h \zs`  (`\ze` is useful as well)

Comment: I have performed the change with `g/\v\.@!\n+/normal gJ`

Comment: @SergioAraujo yes, for this problem, `g` or `v` command may work too